# Как сохранить в localStorage состояние чекбокса и чтобы надпись менялась в зависимости от состояния чекбокса?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чекбокс, состояние которого будет сохраняться в localStorage? Так же нужно что-бы в зависимости от состояния показывалась правильно надпись, если галочка есть, то ВКЛ, если галочки нет, то ВЫКЛ. И куда нужно пихнуть мою функцию  myfunction, что-бы она выполнялась когда галочка есть и не выполнялась когда галочка снята?

```js
myfunction = function {
  alert('Привет!')
}

function onClickBox() {
  let checked = $("#box").is(":checked");
  localStorage.setItem("checked", checked);
  $("#msg").text("Checkbox is checked: " + $("#box").is(":checked"));
}

function onReady() {
  $("#msg").text("Loaded.");
  let checked = "true" == localStorage.getItem("checked");
  $("#box").prop('checked', checked);
  $("#box").click(onClickBox);
}
$(document).ready(onReady);
```

```html
<p id="msg"></p>
<label for="box">CheckBox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="box">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```